# How to Define that One String is Greater than Another? (C#) (Beginner)

Tags: c#

I'm *extremely* new to coding, so the answer/s to this may be obvious. I have to make the card game War. I've created a list of strings like so for a part of the deck:

```
List<string> userDeck = new List<string>
        {
            "2",
            "3",
            "4",
            "5",
            "6",
            "7",
            "8",
            "9",
            "10",
            "Jack",
            "Queen",
            "King",
            "Ace",
        };
```

Is there a way I can instruct the computer that "Jack" will be greater than "10", "Queen" greater than "Jack", and so on? I'm not sure where or how I should do it.

**OR**, if you have any other suggestions as to how I should do this, please let me know. I have to be using a list. I initially made a list of integers instead, but I wasn't aware of an uncomplicated way to assign the names such as "Jack," "Queen," "King," etc. to them for display purposes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try using enums and then it becomes to get them and check if it big or small

Comment: You should create a class Card which has 2 properties: name and value (int or enum). Just create a list of Card and when you need to compare the cards, compare the values. You can override equals and GetHashCode methods, == operator as well to make comparison easier.

Comment: Take a look at Enumerations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/enumeration-types

Comment: You could create a `Dictionary<int, string>()` The `Key` would then contain the worth of the card and the `Value` would contain the name.

Comment: I would create a custom class `Card`. This class contains properties like `Name`(for example `"Jack"`) and `int Value`(for the order). Then add instances of this class in a `List<Card>` and you have both informations.

Comment: Unlike what Sebastian suggested, you might want to use `Dictionary<string, int> cards;` so that the key is the card name and the value is its (yeah) value. For example, if someone got "Jack" then `cards["Jack"]` is the Jack's value you want.

Comment: Or, if you like the concept of using a List you could use List<Tuple<string, int>>. Any way you go, the point is that you need to store two values for each card, the name and the rank.

Comment: @Kevin that could get ugly really quick :p

Comment: @Everyone, agreed it could. However, in this example, we are talking about a deck of playing cards (no more than 52 entries in the list, 13 if you are ignoring suit) and the point of my comment was more to point out that two values per card are required to rank the cards.

Comment: @Kevin I get it, but since she's new I thought she could really get confused by tuples. Just trying to make it simple enough.

Comment: @Everyone - point taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create a object called "Card". This object can contain more than a value. Eg:

```
public class MyCard
{
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public int Value {get;set;}

     public MyCard(string name, int value)
     {
         this.Name = name;
         this.Value = value;
     }
}
```

After create this object, you will use this at your list.

```
List<MyCard> userDeck = new List<MyCard>();
```

You can fill the list this way:

```
usertDeck.Add(new MyCard("2", 1));
....
usertDeck.Add(new MyCard("K", 11));
```

So, to compare 2 cards, just check using the "Value" variable

Comment: This might be a good candidate for a `struct` since it's relatively small and you expect immutability.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it allows duplicates. You should consider using a `enum` or a collection that has a key, like a `Dictionary<string, int>`

Comment: @bradbury9 in the context of OP's post (war) duplicates are actually going to be a game mechanic (suit is ignored).  For an all-purpose card class outside of this scope though, an `enum` for rank and suit is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Vincius's answer but with some changes for better usability:

```
  enum Suit
  {
    Clubs = 1,
    Diamonds = 2,
    Hearts = 3,
    Spades = 4
  }

  class Card
  {
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, int> rankMap = new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
      {"2", 2 },
      {"3", 3 },
      {"4", 4 },
      {"5", 5 },
      {"6", 6 },
      {"7", 7 },
      {"8", 8 },
      {"9", 9 },
      {"10", 10 },
      {"Jack", 11 },
      {"Queen", 12 },
      {"King", 13 },
      {"Ace", 14 },
    };


    private Suit suit;
    private string rank;

    public Suit Suit => suit;
    public string Rank => rank;
    public int Value { get { return rankMap[rank]; } }

    public Card(Suit s, string r)
    {
      suit = s;
      rank = r;
    }
  }
```

The way you can use it:

```
  Card c1 = new Card(1, "Jack");  // 1 is Clubs
  Card c2 = new Card(4, "Queen"); // 4 is Spades
  Console.WriteLine(c1.Value); // prints 11
  Console.WriteLine(c2.Value); // prints 12
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to refactor your code (to your requirements value per card) is to use Tuple's instead of string type in generic List as follow:

```
List<Tuple<int,string>> userDeck = new List<Tuple<int,string>>
        {
            new Tuple<int,string>(2,"2"),
            new Tuple<int,string>(3,"3"),
            new Tuple<int,string>(4,"4"),
            new Tuple<int,string>(5,"5"),
            new Tuple<int,string>(6,"6"),
            new Tuple<int,string>(7,"7"),
            new Tuple<int,string>(8,"8"),
            new Tuple<int,string>(9,"9"),
            new Tuple<int,string>(10,"10"),
            new Tuple<int,string>(11,"Jack"),
            new Tuple<int,string>(12,"Queen"),
            new Tuple<int,string>(13,"King"),
            new Tuple<int,string>(14,"Ace"),
        };
```